# Failed to add fdf with attachment annotation

Tags: annotations, itext, attachment, fdf

I work on an application to add annotation from a fdf file to a Pdf file
With iText can do in this way

```
FdfReader aFdfReader = new FdfReader(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
PdfReader aReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(args[1]));
PdfStamper aStamper = new PdfStamper(aReader, new FileOutputStream(args[2]));
aStamper.addComments(aFdfReader);
aStamper.close();
```

But when i load the fdf I have this exception. The fdf have an annotation with the type attachment file.

Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: Error reading string at file pointer 5106590
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.throwError(PRTokeniser.java:220)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.nextToken(PRTokeniser.java:411)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.nextValidToken(PRTokeniser.java:282)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPRObject(PdfReader.java:1908)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readArray(PdfReader.java:1891)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPRObject(PdfReader.java:1946)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDictionary(PdfReader.java:1877)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPRObject(PdfReader.java:1913)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDocObj(PdfReader.java:1411)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FdfReader.readPdf(FdfReader.java:105)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:181)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:395)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(PdfReader.java:415)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FdfReader.(FdfReader.java:92)
    at com.artesys.pdf.itext.pdf.AddFdf.main(AddFdf.java:18)

I do the test with itext_so.pdf to attach to the annotation

if i made the test with a helloword i works fine

I used the version 5.5.9

Thank in advance for your response

Regards

Fabien

Comment: The exception occurs while reading the FDF. Can you share it for inspection?

Comment: Give me your email can send it. Anyway it can be easy to generate it, it's an attach file annotation and the pdf attach is the itext documentation itext_so.pdf

Comment: You can send the FDF to the email address in the free text on my stackoverflow profile page.

Comment: Isn't it better to put the file on a file sharing website?

Answer (score 0):

The FDF is special as it contains a PDF in a stream; this PDF stream is partially uncompressed; thus, PDF syntax, in particular PDF indirect object starts are visible.

And the `FdfReader` works incorrectly: It assumes these starts of indirect objects in a stream content to be top level FDF object starts and fails when trying to read those objects.

One can quick-fix this by making the `FdfReader` object reading more forgiving.

### The FDF

Your FDF looks like this:

```
%FDF-1.2
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</FDF<</Annots[2 0 R]/F(http://localhost:8780/PachaServer/downloadpacha?pathpdf=Rendition.pdf&edit=false&loginname=fhfgh)/ID[<2175D5400E41761374A2EB01E7026C68><5E9C3BFFF121CE737ED66FF7318CA58D>]/UF(http://localhost:8780/PachaServer/downloadpacha?pathpdf=Rendition.pdf&edit=false&loginname=fhfgh)>>/Type/Catalog/Version/1.6>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</C[0.25 0.333328 1.0]/Contents(itext_so.pdf)/CreationDate(D:20160519150439+02'00')/F 28/FS 3 0 R/M(D:20160519150439+02'00')/NM(79bcf116-d9bd-4ade-a8cd-7575351271fd)/Name/Paperclip/Page 0/RC(<?xml version="1.0"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:15.16.0" xfa:spec="2.0.2" ><p>itext_so.pdf</p></body>)/Rect[183.106 684.663 190.106 701.663]/Subj(Pièce jointe)/Subtype/FileAttachment/T(Fabien.Levalois)/Type/Annot>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</EF<</F 4 0 R>>/F(itext_so.pdf)/Type/Filespec/UF(itext_so.pdf)>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</DL 10536008/Filter/FlateDecode/Length 10207532/Params<</CheckSum("}þ¶îô/Óý‡†d’ÒÎ)/CreationDate(D:20160511112202+02'00')/ModDate(D:20160511112205+02'00')/Size 10536008>>/Subtype/application#2Fpdf>>stream
... [10207532 data bytes] ...
endstream
endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF
```

This structure is correct. But the contents of the big stream, the 10207532 data bytes in object 4 are special: They constitute a PDF document, and as this document already is compressed, it partially could not be compressed any further when embedded into the FDF and the original PDF syntax becomes piecewise visible, e.g. some 660000 bytes into the stream there suddenly are byte sequences which represent an end of the current PDF stream and the start of another indirect PDF object:

```
endstream
endobj
10283 0 obj
<</Extends 10282 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode/First 1139/Length 4195/N 100/Type/ObjStm>>stream
...
endstream
endobj
10284 0 obj
<</Extends 10282 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode/First 1139/Length 4018/N 100/Type/ObjStm>>stream
...
endstream
endobj
10285 0 obj
<</Extends 10282 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode/First 190/Length 1001/N 18/Type/ObjStm>>stream
```

etc. etc. etc.

As these PDF objects only are piecewise visible, though, trying to read them as is can result in an error.

### The `FdfReader`

As an FDF does not need to contain a cross reference section, the `FdfReader` as a first step tries to create one by searching the file for byte sequences which appear to be the start of indirect objects and deriving a cross reference section from that.

This is incorrect, though, because in cases like your FDF it creates many false cross reference entries, and while reading these false indirect objects, errors occur unless the false objects are syntactically correct.

In case of your PDF many false objects are syntactically correct until a location near the offset 5106590 mentioned in the exception where a false indirect object is partially re-compressed. And when trying to reading that, `FdfReader` throws the exception you observed.

But the problem are not only such syntax errors (these could be caught and ignored after all) but that false objects and true objects may have the same object number. Thus, `FdfReader` might use a false object instead of a true one!

### A quick fix

While the cross reference reconstruction code for the `FdfReader` fundamentally has to be re-implemented for a true fix, there is a quick fix for it allowing it to properly process FDFs in which the "false FDF objects" do not collide with true ones, simply derive a class from `FdfReader` and override the method `readPRObject()` like this:

```
@Override
protected PdfObject readPRObject() throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        return super.readPRObject();
    }
    catch (InvalidPdfException e)
    {
        return PdfNull.PDFNULL;
    }
}
```

*([ImprovedFdfReader.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/form/ImprovedFdfReader.java))*

While reading the provided FDF [itext-SO.fdf](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext5/form/itext-SO.fdf) using the [ReadFdf.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/form/ReadFdf.java#L35) test method `testReadFdfFabienLevalois` with a normal `FdfReader` fails, doing so using the test method `testReadFdfFabienLevaloisImproved` with an `ImprovedFdfReader` succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
You say that the fdf is broken because the content is broken.
 I use an Itext document to be sure that the problem doesn't come from the Pdf. I use acrobat DC to generate the fdf for the same raison (submitFrom action), and in your response  you say that the problem doesn't come from the Itext librairy. 
To confirm that the problem come from the Pdf itext_SO.pdf I create a PDF with the same annotation and I load with PdfReader, in that case I have no trouble.

Comment: It means that the PDF is broken when it is include in a FDF and is not broken when it is include in PDF. I compare the stream object between Fdf and PDF  is the same .

Comment: Probably, I was a bit too quick when saying "*there suddenly are byte sequences which can safely be assumed not to be some Flate encoded*". Probably Flate encoding could not compress those blocks in any way and added them without change. In that case the FDF would not be broken and merely the incorrect implementation of FDF reading in the `FdfReader` would remain.

Comment: @FabienLevalois I completely overhauled the answer. The FDF looks proper, and I provided a quick fix which should work more often than not. It is not a complete fix, though; for a complete fix the `FdfReader` has to get its own, specialized cross reference rebuilding method.

Comment: Big Thanks for your help

Comment: @FabienLevalois If the answer helps, please accept it (click on the tick to its upper left).

Comment: The quick fix doesn't work, in fact the FdfReader extended can allow to read the Fdf, but if it used to add to a stamper the PDF result of the stamper doesn't contain a correct annotation with the attached PDF. So the complete fix is needed to solve my problem.